# Directory check returning false in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm having an issue with a Node.js function. I'm fairly certain that it is just an issue with the function being asynchronous but I want to be sure. I am checking to see if a certain path that was entered by the user is valid by checking if it exists.

```
var directoryExists = exports.directoryExists = function(filePath) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   if (fs.statSync(filePath).isDirectory()){
     resolve("Valid");
   } else {
     reject("Invalid");
   }
 });
}
```

These are my calls to the function:

```
 files.directoryExists(sourcePath).then((msg) => {
   console.log(msg);
 }).catch(function(){
   console.error("Promise Rejected");
 });

 files.directoryExists(destPath).then((msg) => {
   console.log(msg);
 }).catch(function(){
   console.error("Promise Rejected");
 });
```

I'm very new to the whole concept of asynchronous programming and promises so this is becoming quite frustrating. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks good. Are you shure the directory exists?

Comment: at a glance, i don't see anything wrong but I wanted to add that you should probably be using `fs.stat` instead of `fs.statSync`. You're already using a promise so it's already async so you can use the async `fs.stat` and in the callback, you can resolve whether or not it's a directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really the asynchronous thing that's catching you out, although there's a change you can make to improve that.

`statSync` can throw an exception (if the path doesn't match anything, for instance); you're not handling that, and so when it throws, that gets converted into a rejection. If you looked at the argument you're getting in your `catch` handler, you'd see the exception that it raises.

The async improvement is that since you're using a `Promise`, there's no reason to use `statSync`. Just use `stat` so you don't tie up the JavaScript thread unnecessarily.

So something along the lines of:

```
var directoryExists = exports.directoryExists = function(filePath) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Make the request asynchronous
        fs.stat(filePath, function(err, data) {
            // If there was an error or it wasn't a directory...
            if (err || !data.isDirectory()) {
                // ...reject
                reject(err || new Error("Not a directory");
            } else {
                // All good
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Of course, you may choose to have it resolve with `false` if the thing isn't a directory or any of several other choices; this just gets you further along.

---

For instance, having an *error* still be a rejection, but resolving with `true`/`false` for whether something that exists is a directory; this provides the maximum amount of information to the caller but makes them work a bit harder if all they care about is true/false:

```
var directoryExists = exports.directoryExists = function(filePath) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Make the request asynchronous
        fs.stat(filePath, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                // Reject on error
                reject(err);
            } else {
                // Return result on success
                resolve(data.isDirectory());
            }
        });
    });
};
```

or making it always resolve, with `false` if there's no match or there is a match but it's not a directory:

```
var directoryExists = exports.directoryExists = function(filePath) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        // Make the request asynchronous
        fs.stat(filePath, function(err, data) {
            resolve(!err && data.isDirectory());
        });
    });
};
```

Lots of ways for this function to behave, it's up to you.

Comment: ...although now I think about it, if you provided a *valid* path, you wouldn't get an exception out of `statSync`. The above works for both valid and invalid paths at my end, though, so...

Comment: I think I was just overcomplicating it. I think I could make the statSync work but your solution is much more straight forward. Thanks!